# What is the definition of $\infty$

Tags: definition, infinity

I saw in a note that say $\infty$ is not a real number, and there is no interval of the form $(a, \infty]$?
So what is the definintion of $\infty$?

Comment: There is no standalone definition of $\infty$. But there *are* definitions of various expressions that involve the symbol $\infty$. In particular, there is a definition of $(a,\infty)$.  Note that there is nothing peculiar about this. There is no standalone definition of $a$ either, or of $($.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yeah, you're right, I would mention that $a$ maybe a real number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symbol "$\infty$" is part of the ordinary mathematical alphabet. Like many other symbols in the mathematical alphabet, it has various uses. There is no standalone definition of $\infty$.  There are, however, precise definitions of various *expressions* that use the letter $\infty$.

In particular, in analysis, there *is* a definition of what is meant by the interval $(a,\infty)$. Note that there is nothing peculiar about the fact that there is no standalone definition of $\infty$, while some expressions that use $\infty$ have a clear conventional meaning. There is no standalone definition of $a$ either, or of $($.

**Comment**: Perhaps the following analogy will be useful. Suppose that we have written a program that finds, for any $n$, the $n$-th decimal digit of $\pi$. Then the command "Print $[17, 42]$" might mean print all the digits from the $17$-th to the $42$-th, inclusive. The command "Print $[17, 42)$" could be used to mean print from the $17$-th (inclusive) to the $42$-th (exclusive).  And if we wanted to print all the digits from the $17$-th on, we might issue the command "Print $[17,\infty)$".  But the command "Print $[17,\infty]$ would make no sense, no reasonable meaning can be assigned to the phrase "the $\infty$-th digit of $\pi$."

Comment: You might want to add the two lines giving the definition for $(a,\infty)$ in the real analysis context.

Comment: Since we're suggesting edits, how about a quick comment about how $(a, \infty)$ can be defined in the real analysis context?

Comment: Sorry, I meant " ] " above!

Answer (score 5):

You could also use $\infty$ as the point that compactifies $\mathbb{C}.$
Thus, it is convenient to use the point at infinity when constructing the Riemann sphere. So, in topology, it is used to  compactify certain topological spaces.

Comment: Including the real line ...

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of different concepts of infinity in mathematics.  When used in interval notation of this kind, something like $(5,\infty)$ means the set of all real numbers greater than $5$.  Similarly $[5,\infty)$ means the set of all real numbers greater than or equal to $5$.